# Call to overloaded to_string ambiguous

Tags: c++, c++11

I have two files: error.h and error.cpp. Compiling with

```
g++ -std=c++0x
```

gives me an error:

```
error.cpp:9:33:**call of overloaded "to_string(char*&)" is ambiguous**
```

How can i fix this problem?

error.h:

```
  1 #ifndef ERROR_H_GUARD
  2 #define ERROR_H_GUARD
  4 #include <string>
  6 class Error {
  7   public:
  8     Error(int pos, std::string& msg); 
 10     Error(int pos, char* msg); 
 12     const char* what() throw();
 14   private:
 15     std::string msg;
 17     void setMsg(int pos, std::string& msg);
 18 };
 19 
 20 #endif
```

error.cpp:

```
  2 #include "error.h"
  4 Error::Error(int pos, std::string& msg){
  5   setMsg(pos, msg);
  6 }
  8 Error::Error(int pos, char* msg) {
  9   setMsg(pos, std::to_string(msg));
 10 }   
 12 const char* Error::what() throw() {
 13   return msg.c_str();
 14 } 
 16 void Error::setMsg(int pos, std::string& msg){
 17   this->msg = std::to_string(pos) + msg + std::string("\n") + std::string(pos - 1, ' ') + std::string("^");
 18 }
```

Comment: `char* msg` should be `const char* msg`. And your `std::string&` should be `const std::string&`. Remeber to use const by default.

Comment: You could have made easily a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) and post that (if you then wouldn't have found it out yourself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`to_string()` is used to **convert** something which is *not* a string (e.g. a `long`, an `int`, etc.) into a `string`. You have a `char*`, which is a C string, and what you want to do is to create a `string` object out of it, not *convert* it.

Your compiler complains about **ambiguity** because it cannot find a version of `to_string()` for the type you are passing to it (`char*`), which makes sense, considering the purpose of that function.

If you declared your parameter `string const&` rather than `string&` in the corresponding overload of `setMsg()` (and in the constructor of `Error` as well), you could directly invoke it by passing C strings: a temporary of type `string` would be created automatically and bound to the argument of `setMsg()`.

This way you would even **get rid** of the specific overload of `setMsg()` for C strings, which in fact does nothing but forwarding.

Answer (score 3):

[std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) takes integer as parameter, but you pass a pointer to it.

```
Error::Error(int pos, char* msg) {
  setMsg(pos, std::to_string(msg));
}
```

You don't need to translate a string to string, try:

```
Error::Error(int pos, char* msg) {
     setMsg(pos, std::string(msg));
}
```

Side Note: all your function parameter better take const reference:

```
Error(int pos, const std::string& msg);
void setMsg(int pos, const std::string& msg);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `string`'s constructor instead:

```
std::string(msg)
```

However note that this temporary can't bind to the reference argument. You'll have to fix that.

Maybe like this:

```
Error::Error(int pos, char* msg) {
   std::string str(msg);
   setMsg(pos, msg);
}
```

Or use const-ref.

Comment: That won't work here, because the `Error` constructor requires a non-const reference.  That seems like a bug in the design, though.

Comment: No need to use the constructor explicitly, passing the `const char*` would also work.

Answer (score 1):

Drop `Error(int pos, char* msg)` and change the remaining constructor and `setMsg()` to

```
Error(int pos, const std::string& msg);
...
void setMsg(int pos, const std::string& msg);
```

When you call `Error()` with a `char*`, it will automatically use the `std::string` constructor. So, there's no need for a separate constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work:

```
Error::Error(int pos, char* msg) {
   setMsg(pos, std::to_string(msg));
}
```

Because [**`std::to_string()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) takes a **numeric** value to convert. You probably meant:

```
Error::Error(int pos, char const * msg) {
   setMsg(pos, msg);
}
```

Which is exactly the same as the `std::string&` version (which, in turn, should be `std::string const &`), so you could actually just remove this `char*` constructor (less code to maintain: bonus)!

Also this:

```
void Error::setMsg(int pos, std::string& msg){
```

Should probably be this:

```
void Error::setMsg(int pos, std::string const & msg){
```

Comment: won't work either because of the non-const string reference of setMsg.